# Foxpro String Variable combination in Forloop

Tags: sql, visual-foxpro

As in title, there is an error in my first code in FOR loop: Command contains unrecognized phrase. I am thinking if the method string+variable is wrong.

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD COLUMN prod_n c(10)
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD COLUMN prm1 n(19,2)  
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD COLUMN rbon1 n(19,2)
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD COLUMN total1 n(19,2)
```

There are prm2... until total5, in which the numbers represent the month.

```
FOR i=1 TO 5
    REPLACE ALL prm+i WITH amount FOR LEFT(ALLTRIM(a),1)="P" AND 
    batch_mth = i
    REPLACE ALL rbon+i WITH amount FOR LEFT(ALLTRIM(a),1)="R" 
AND batch_mth = i
    REPLACE ALL total+i WITH sum((prm+i)+(rbon+i)) FOR batch_mth = i
NEXT
ENDFOR
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: @KenWhite thanks for replying. Meaning to say that I've to use REPLACE command one by one? As the combination does not work in this way.

Comment: @KenWhite, that is not true. You can reference fields in a replace command using variables as long as you treat them as name expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of things wrong with the code you posted above.  Cetin has mentioned a number of them, so I apologize if I duplicate some of them.

PROBLEM 1 - in your **ALTER TABLE** commands I do not see where you create fields prm2, prm3, prm4, prm5, rbon2, rbon3, etc.
And yet your FOR LOOP would be trying to write to those fields as the FOR LOOP expression **i** increases from 1 to 5 - if the other parts of your code was correct.

PROBLEM 2 - You cannot concatenate a String to an Integer so as to create a Field Name like you attempt to do with **prm+i** or **rbon+1**

Cetin's code suggestions would work (again as long as you had the #2, #3, etc. fields defined).  However in Foxpro and Visual Foxpro you can generally do a task in a variety of ways.

Personally, for readability I'd approach your FOR LOOP like this:

```
FOR i=1 TO 5
   * --- Keep in mind that unless fields #2, #3, #4, & #5 are defined ---
   * --- The following will Fail ---
   cFld1 = "prm" + STR(i,1)  && define the 1st field
   cFld2 = "rbon" + STR(i,1)  && define the 2nd field
   cFld3 = "total" + STR(i,1)  && define the 3rd field

   REPLACE ALL &cFld1 WITH amount ;
      FOR LEFT(ALLTRIM(a),1)="P" AND batch_mth = i
   REPLACE ALL &cFld2 WITH amount ;
      FOR LEFT(ALLTRIM(a),1)="R" AND batch_mth = i
   REPLACE ALL &cFld3 WITH sum((prm+i)+(rbon+i)) ;
      FOR batch_mth = i 
NEXT
```

NOTE - it might be good if you would learn to use VFP's Debug tools so that you can examine your code execution line-by-line in the VFP Development mode.  And you can also use it to examine the variable values.
**Breakpoints** are good, but you have to already have the TRACE WINDOW open for the Break to work.
**SET STEP ON** is the Debug command that I generally use so that program execution will stop and AUTOMATICALLY open the TRACE WINDOW for looking at code execution and/or variable values.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Cetin's solution works for "prm" and "rbon" but does not work for total, as it showed up "data type mismatch". I have used your command to define each field name and it works out without fail. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you have fields named prm1, prm2, prm3 ... prm12 that represent the months and you want to update them in a loop? If so, you need to understand that a "fieldName" is a "name" and thus you need to use a "name expression" to use it as a variable. That is:

```
prm+i
```

would NOT work but:

```
( 'pro'+ ltrim(str(m.i)) )
```

would.

For example here is your code revised:

```
For i=1 To 5
    Replace All ('prm'+Ltrim(Str(m.i))) With amount For Left(Alltrim(a),1)="P" And batch_mth = m.i
    Replace All ('rbon'+Ltrim(Str(m.i))) With amount For Left(Alltrim(a),1)="R" And batch_mth = m.i
    * ?????????    REPLACE ALL ('total'+Ltrim(Str(m.i))) WITH sum((prm+i)+(rbon+i)) FOR batch_mth = i
Endfor
```

However, I must admit, your code doesn't make sense to me. Maybe it would be better if you explained what you are trying to do and give some simple data with the result you expect (as code - you can use FAQ 50 on foxite to create code for data).

Comment: Your answer says exactly what my comments did (which you objected to). I just couldn't write an answer because I don't have access to FoxPro currently, and I've learned a long time ago that you don't post untested code here. :-) I've deleted my comments above to avoid any confusion.

Comment: @KenWhite, I got your comments were saying you can't do this. Maybe I misinterpreted your sentences.

Comment: Sorry for late replying. It is the answer yes. I was trying to use the while loop and it is so messy as it keeps on repeating the same command for each i. Thanks for the help and it has been reduced to about 5 lines of coding!